# VB6 Get List of Active Directory Domains

Tags: vb6, active-directory

Using VB6, is it possible to get a list of all available domains in active directory?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Add references for ActiveDS type library, and ADO to your project.

```
Sub GetDomains()
   Dim objRootDSE As IADs
   Dim objBase As IADs
   Dim path As String
   Dim rsDomains As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim cnADS As ADODB.Connection
   Dim cmdCommand As ADODB.Command

   Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")
   path = "LDAP://" & objRootDSE.Get("rootDomainNamingContext")
   Set objBase = GetObject(path)

   Set cnADS = New ADODB.Connection
   cnADS.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
   cnADS.Open "ADSI"

   Set cmdCommand = New ADODB.Command
   cmdCommand.ActiveConnection = cnADS
   cmdCommand.Properties("searchScope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE
   cmdCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Name, distinguishedName FROM '" & objBase.ADsPath & "' WHERE objectCategory = 'domain'"
   Set rsDomains = cmdCommand.Execute

   Do While rsDomains.EOF = False
      List1.AddItem (rsDomains!Name)
      rsDomains.MoveNext
   Loop

End Sub
```

I have only the one domain to test this against so I hope you'll need to let me know if it gets all the domains for you. Also please note, **I didn't add error handling**.